# padding is invalid and cannot be removed c# decrypt

Tags: c#, cryptography

I saw that exists another questions about this topic, but I checked every question and I can't solve my problem..
This is my method to decrypt and another method to call decrypt method with required parameters:

```
public string Decrypt(AesOperationType operationType, byte[] criptotext, byte[] Key, byte[] initVector)
{

        string plaintext = null;

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = initVector;
            if (operationType == AesOperationType.Cbc)
            {
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            }
            else if (operationType == AesOperationType.Cfb)
            {
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            }

            //apelam functia de decriptare 
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(criptotext))

            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Start decrypt for criptotext : " + BitConverter.ToString(criptotext) + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Plaintext after decrypt : " + plaintext + "\n");

        return plaintext;
}

public byte[] Encrypt_Call()
{
        var key = "1212121212121212";
        var key_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        using (Aes aess = Aes.Create())
        {
            var iv = aess.IV;
            cryptdecrypt object = new cryptdecrypt();
            var result = object.Encrypt(AesOperationType.Cbc, "plaintext", key_byte, iv);
            return result;
        }
}

public void Decrypt_Call()
{
        var key = "1212121212121212";
        var key_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        using (Aes aess = Aes.Create())
        {
            var iv = aess.IV;
            cryptdecrypt object = new cryptdecrypt();
            var cryptotext = Encrypt_Call();
            var result = object.Decrypt(AesOperationType.Cbc, cryptotext , key_byte, iv);
        }
}
```

Encrypt method works fine, but at decryption method call, I face this error:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

I also tried to put `csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock()` this line before this line:

```
using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
```

The error disappears and as result I get an empty string.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Where is the IV specified?

Comment: You must use the same key *and* IV for encryption and decryption. It looks like you may be randomly generating the IV in both encrypt and decrypt methods, and they are therefore not going to be the same.

Comment: @KurokawaMasato AesOperationType is a class which contains an enum with Cbc, Cfb..there is no problem there

Comment: @Iridium I solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically an invalid padding error means the decryption failed. In this case with CBC mode the IV is not specified so it will be junk (or random).

Either:

1. Specify an IV of block length (AES 16-bytes).
2. create a random IV on encryption and prepend it to the encrypted data. On decryption split the IV off and use for decryption. <–– Best option